# httr GET request with large query list

Tags: r, curl, get, httr

I have translated this **cURL** command into a `httr:GET()` request in **R**. However, I'm still getting a `400 error` as an `invalide request`. I double checked using the normal **cURL** command in a git terminal and it worked perfectly.

Where is the problem in my translation of **cURL** command to `R httr:GET` query? Do I need to account for the *-G* at the end of the **cURL** in my GET request?

```
$ curl https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint \
  -u YOUR_API_KEY: \
  -d 'segments[0][origin]=ARN' \
  -d 'segments[0][destination]=BCN' \
  -d 'segments[1][origin]=BCN' \
  -d 'segments[1][destination]=ARN' \
  -d 'cabin_class=economy' \
  -d 'currencies[]=SEK' \
  -d 'currencies[]=USD' \
  -G
```

In **R**:

```r
r <- GET("https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint/",
    authenticate(api.key,""),
    query = list(
        "segments[0][origin]"="ARN",
        "segments[0][destination]"="BCN",
        "segments[1][origin]"="BCN",
        "segments[1][destination]"="ARN",
        "cabin_class"="ecomony",
        "currencies[]"="SEK",
        "currencies[]"="USD"))
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your API key in the body of the query?

Comment: I have tried other ways of authentication, and every time it returned authentication failue. However, in this current state, I get an invalid request error, which leads me to believe it is passing the HTTPS basic authentication successfully